# Grapql query sent as a raw string does not return full next page token

Tags: c#, .net, http, graphql, postman

I have a problem concerning GraphQL. When I send a normal GraphQL request everything is fine, but when I send request as raw json the pagination token gets truncated. Why is that?

GraphQL request is sent as raw json:
[image: GraphQL request is sent as raw json]

Normal GraphQL request:
[image: Normal GraphQL request]